# Удаление повторов в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
[{"id":256,"owner":"2","to":"1","message":"312"},
{"id":257,"owner":"2","to":"1","message":"312"},
{"id":258,"owner":"1","to":"1","message":"3125"},
{"id":259,"owner":"3","to":"1","message":"3162"},
{"id":260,"owner":"2","to":"1","message":"3125"}]
```

В котором значение `to` всегда одинаковое, `message` как повезет(совпадет или нет), а `owner` разное, с повторениями, как удалить все повторения, которые встречаются в `owner` и оставить по 1 значению с наибольшим `id`(То есть последнее)

Пробовал воспользоваться функцией `array_unique` но она удаляет всё, так как `to` у всех одинаковое

Comment: прикладывайте к вопросу вывод команды var_export, собирать тестовый массив из ваших данных немногие захотят

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer в данном случае приведен `json`, получить из этого массив можно простым вызовом `json_decode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение, при условии что данные предварительно отсортированы по id :

```
$data = [
    ["id" => 256, "owner" => "2", "to" => "1", "message" => "312"],
    ["id" => 257, "owner" => "2", "to" => "1", "message" => "312"],
    ["id" => 258, "owner" => "1", "to" => "1", "message" => "3125"],
    ["id" => 259, "owner" => "3", "to" => "1", "message" => "3162"],
    ["id" => 260, "owner" => "2", "to" => "1", "message" => "3125"]
];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $ret[$item['owner']] = $item;
}

var_dump($ret);
```

Answer (score 3):

Если сортировка в массиве будет по ID, то можно попробовать такой способ

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

$values = '[
    {"id":256,"owner":"2","to":"1","message":"312"},
    {"id":257,"owner":"2","to":"1","message":"312"},
    {"id":258,"owner":"1","to":"1","message":"3125"},
    {"id":259,"owner":"3","to":"1","message":"3162"},
    {"id":260,"owner":"2","to":"1","message":"3125"}
]';

$values = json_decode($values, true);
$array = [];

foreach($values as $val){
    $array[$val['owner']] = [
        'id' => $val['id'],
        'to' => $val['to'],
        'message' => $val['message']
    ];
}

var_dump($array);

?>
```

[(выполнить код в rextester)](http://rextester.com/QTZQP39126)